# add_rewrite_rule not working for page var

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I have a page called `mypage` and a custom query var called `mycustomvar`, I am trying to rewrite the following url:

```
http://example.com/index.php?name=mypage&mycustomvar=someword
```

to

```
http://example.com/mypage/someword
```

using

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^mypage/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?name=mypage&mycustomvar=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

But all I get is:

```
http://example.com/mypage/?mycustomvar=someword
```

showing in the url. I have also tried adding both

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%mycustomvar%', '([^/]+)' );
```

as well as making sure that `mycustomvar` is added to my custom query vars via the `query_vars` filter

(and I have tried various combos with and without page name, and using `page` or `pagename` in place of `name`, all with no luck)

Comment: `name` is the query var for post type `post`, `pagename` is for post type `page`.

Comment: interesting, because this is a page, not a post, and `name` worked better, at least for the first variable...

Comment: What do you mean by worked better? If it redirects, that means the original query failed and it found the closest match.

Comment: I mean that when using `name`, it rewrote at least the first part of my url correctly, whereas using `pagename` it did not.

Comment: If you have a link with just query string arguments, it's not going to redirect to the pretty version, that's not what rewrite rules do. You may see a partially rewritten URL when you incorrectly use `name`, because that query is failing, and WP is querying for any post type that matches `mypage`, and redirecting there. Rewrite rules just match requests against rules and convert them to query vars, outputting that rewritten URL is a separate and unrelated task.

Comment: I apologize I am not being clear. Let me put it this way: the url that I want to work is http://example.com/mypage/someword and my rewrite rule above does NOT work in any of those combos, if I add my someword variable to the end and enter the url into the browser, it simply disappears, leaving http://example.com/mypage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's first get some definitive clarification on the proper query vars.

Refer to [Post and Page parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) on the `WP_Query` codex page.

> name (string) - use post slug.
>
> pagename (string) - use page slug.

We can confirm this with `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
    'name' => 'mypage'
);
$mypage = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $mypage );
echo '</pre>';
```

which will produce:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_name = 'mypage'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

It's looking for `mypage` slug in the `post` post type. If we change this to `pagename`, it looks in the `page` post type.

The reason it *kind of* works on the main query with `name` is due to the [`redirect_guess_404_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_guess_404_permalink) function, which kicks in when the original request is a 404. It runs another query to find the closest match and redirect there, if something is found. This also results in any extra parameters getting stripped from the URL.

One important thing to note with hierarchical post types- if your page is a child of another page, you must set the `pagename` query var with the `parent/child` path, as different parents can have children with the same slug.

As for your question, changing the query var to `pagename` works with your original code in v4.7.2 and the Twenty Sixteen theme:

```
function wpd_mypage_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag(
        '%mycustomvar%',
        '([^/]+)'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^mypage/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=mypage&mycustomvar=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_mypage_rewrite' );
```

Note that I used `add_rewrite_tag` here. You could *instead* use the [`query_vars` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars). The reason `add_rewrite_tag` works is that it internally adds the query var via the same filter.

Don't forget to [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after adding / changing rules. You can also do this by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page.

You can then `echo get_query_var( 'mycustomvar' );` in the template, and the value is output.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had exactly that code in there (as you can see in my original question above) and for some reason it wasn't working (even after flushing the permalinks), but for some reason now it does. I am stumped, but I like your explanation of the redirect guess function (which is new to me), so I will accept this as the answer. (perhaps in my combo tries of pagename, name, and page I left out the rewrite tag or query vars, but in any event it now works and thanks)

Comment: +10 how dare you to be so informative!.. this is so cool.. I was stuck fixing add_rewrite_rules but nothing was working.. this "page type" or "post type" was the main thing I was not able to solve without it.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

UGH I (maybe) just figured it out. I didn't need my variable to have a name, just a location.

So changing my rewrite rule to this worked:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^mypage/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=mypage&$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

NOW my page will properly load the URL:

```
http://example.com/mypage/someword
```

ALTHOUGH that said, I have no way now other than url placement to read my variable `someword` and do something with it, but I guess that is good enough unless someone can point me to a better way that will allow me to query that var by its name....